# How to get configurable product's custom attribute's values or value by attribute id in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I tried to get it but i just getting label and options but not get selected value.

Answer (score 1):

Get attribute value this way :

`<?php
$attribute_code = 'brand';
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>`